# Android studio Display image from Laravel API

Tags: android, laravel, picasso, rest

I am using Retrofit API to access my Laravel site data. I am not able to display images in my android app.

Here is my Laravel code to save images in my Laravel site.

```
 $path = 'images/no-thumbnail.jpeg';

    if($request->has('thumbnail')){
        $extension = ".".$request->thumbnail->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $name = basename($request->thumbnail->getClientOriginalName(), $extension).time();
        $name = $name.$extension;
        $path = $request->thumbnail->storeAs('images', $name, 'public');
    }
```

Here is the API response for the Products tabel.

```
[{"id":1,"user_id":"1","title":"White T shirt","description":"White T shirt small size","categorie":"1","price":"50","discount_price":"0","thumbnail":"images\/81vzc0ciKwL._AC_UX679_1619280040.jpg","slug":"white-t-shirt","options":null,"featured":"0","status":"0","created_at":"2021-04-24T16:00:40.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-04-24T16:00:40.000000Z","deleted_at":null}]
```

The response of the image is this  "thumbnail":"images/81vzc0ciKwL._AC_UX679_1619280040.jpg"

For my android app, I am using Picasso here is the code.

```
Picasso.get().load(shopesModel.getThumbnail()).into(holder.shopImg);
```

But still, I am not getting images in my android app. I am getting other fields of the product table.

Here is the screenshot of the app

[image]

Where should I change my code. Laraval or change my app code so that I can get images from Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your json response doesn't have qualified url in  thumbnail

```
"thumbnail":"images\/81vzc0ciKwL._AC_UX679_1619280040.jpg"
```

There two ways you can fix
1.best solution is to send full url image path from server side
2.hardcoding base url in your android and append to Picasso

```
"thumbnail":"https://urdomain/storage/images/81vzc0ciKwL._AC_UX679_1619280040.jpg"
```

or

```
String baseUrl="https://urdomain/storage/";

Picasso.get().load(baseUrl+shopesModel.getThumbnail()).into(holder.shopImg);
```

Comment: I tried 2nd method but still not get the image.

Comment: just print baseUrl+shopesModel.getThumbnail() and see what you get.and access that url in browser

Comment: may be in server side your images in storage.if that case  https://urdomain/storage/images/81vzc0ciKwL._AC_UX679_1619280040.jpg

Comment: Picasso.get().load(Constant.URL+shopesModel.getThumbnail()).into(holder.shopImg);

public class Constant {
    public static final String URL = "http://192.168.43.24/"; 
}

Is this the right way to enter the hardcoding base URL?

Comment: first load that iamge in browser so you copy that url and paster to base url .you need http or https also

Comment: @AliTariq.glad that you solved your issue

Comment: my problem is solved by urdomain/storage/images/81vzc0ciKwL._AC_UX679_1619280040.jpg this link thanks alot.